# Preserve the Laplacian operator

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

[image]

My try:

$$\zeta  = r_{11}x  + r_{12}y$$
$$\eta = r_{21}x + r_{22}y$$

if we invert the matrix $R$, we get:

$$D^{-1}(\zeta \cdot r_{22} - \eta \cdot r_{12}) = x $$
$$D^{-1}(\eta \cdot r_{11} - \zeta \cdot r_{21}) = y$$

Where $D$ is the discriminant of $R$.

However I get $0$ if I differentiate two times.

Does anybody know how to do this correctly ?